# When printing Node command line arguments, why are forward slashes being removed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vscode-extensions

In a Node command I have passed two arguments--each a file name. When I print the command line arguments to the console using the `console.log(process.argv)`, the last argument is missing the slash delimiters in the path. Any ideas why, or how to troubleshoot this? Here is the output.

```
[
'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
'c:\\Users\\66851\\development\\projectb\\file-changed.js',
'c:Users66851developmentprojectbtest-file.js'
]
```

#### Details

The details are that the Node command is actually a command that is run by a VSCode extension: [Run on Save](https://github.com/emeraldwalk/vscode-runonsave), which executes a file (`file-changed.js`) containing the aforementioned console.log command. I've posted this issue at their GitHub repo, but there has been no reply. The Run on Save settings in this case are:

```
"emeraldwalk.runonsave": {
  "shell": "C:/Program Files/Git/bin/bash.exe",
  "commands": [
    {
      "cmd": "node file-changed.js ${file}"
    },
  ]
},
```

#### Of Note

I have a *separate* Node project, configured identically with the Run on Save extension. In that project this issue is not present.

Comment: It seems the `file` being passed to the runonsave is not having the correct path. As, the third value in the array is the first argument provided to the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the cause of my issue.  It was due to this line in my `settings.json` file:

`"shell": "C:/Program Files/Git/bin/bash.exe",`

Once I removed that, my issue went away.